# Problem with greater than symbol in Regex, C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to extract a specific tag from html (I know from reading on this site that you should not try and parse html with regular expressions, but I only need specific tags, that follows a pretty specific order)

This is the regular expression (tested in Expresso) and working perfectly as it should

```
(?<ExternalSource2>\<eds2[\s.]+url\=\"?(?<Url>[\w\./:\?=&\+%\d_-]+)\"?[\s.]*\>(?<Text>[\s.]*[\w\s\d]*)\</eds2\>)
```

The problem comes when trying to use this in C# this code

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"(?<ExternalSource2>\<eds2[\s.]+url\=\""?(?<Url>[\w\./:\?=&\+%\d_-]+)\""?[\s.]*\>(?<Text>[\s.]*[\w\s\d]*)\</eds2\>)");

        string Input = @"width: 662px; height: 60px; vertical-align: middle""><eds2 url=""http://www.someurl.co.uk/_modules/system/Newsletter.aspx?Username=TBO&Password=N5TBO2&TagID=PlaceLogo&TownID=147"">PlaceLogo</eds2></td></tr></tbody></table><table style=""width: 662px; border-collapse: collapse""><tbod";

        foreach (Match m in re.Matches(Input)) {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("Match : {0}<br/>", m));
            short i = 0;
            foreach (Group g in m.Groups) {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("Group {0} = {1}<br/>", i++, g.Value));
            }
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<br/><br/>");
        }
```

Produces this result :

```
Match : PlaceLogo
Group 0 = PlaceLogo
Group 1 = PlaceLogo
Group 2 = http://www.someurl.co.uk/_modules/system/Newsletter.aspx?Username=TBO&Password=N5TBO2&TagID=PlaceLogo&TownID=147
Group 3 = PlaceLogo
```

which is not at all what I expect.

When you use the code below though, the result is more what I would expect (but still not quite) :

```
    Regex re = new Regex(@"eds2[\s.]+url\=\""?(?<Url>[\w\./:\?=&\+%\d_-]+)\""?[\s.]*\>(?<Text>[\s.]*[\w\s\d]*)\</eds2\>");
```

Result :

```
Match : eds2 url="http://www.someurl.co.uk/_modules/system/Newsletter.aspx?Username=TBO&Password=N5TBO2&TagID=PlaceLogo&TownID=147">PlaceLogo
Group 0 = eds2 url="http://www.someurl.co.uk/_modules/system/Newsletter.aspx?Username=TBO&Password=N5TBO2&TagID=PlaceLogo&TownID=147">PlaceLogo
Group 1 = http://www.someurl.co.uk/_modules/system/Newsletter.aspx?Username=TBO&Password=N5TBO2&TagID=PlaceLogo&TownID=147
Group 2 = PlaceLogo
```

The expected output is :

```
Match : <eds2 url="http://www.someurl.co.uk/_modules/system/Newsletter.aspx?Username=TBO&Password=N5TBO2&TagID=PlaceLogo&TownID=147">PlaceLogo</eds2>

Group 0 = <eds2 url="http://www.someurl.co.uk/_modules/system/Newsletter.aspx?Username=TBO&Password=N5TBO2&TagID=PlaceLogo&TownID=147">PlaceLogo</eds2>

Group 1 = <eds2 url="http://www.someurl.co.uk/_modules/system/Newsletter.aspx?Username=TBO&Password=N5TBO2&TagID=PlaceLogo&TownID=147">PlaceLogo</eds2>

Group 2 = http://www.someurl.co.uk/_modules/system/Newsletter.aspx?Username=TBO&Password=N5TBO2&TagID=PlaceLogo&TownID=147

Group 3 = PlaceLogo
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you want to extract? Can you tell us what is the expected output?

Comment: I added the expected output above, which is what someone else got as well, but unfortunately its not what I am getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem with your sample code. It creates the following output:

```
Match : <eds2 url="http://www.someurl.co.uk/_modules/system/Newsletter.aspx?Username=TBO&Password=N5TBO2&TagID=PlaceLogo&TownID=147">PlaceLogo</eds2>

Group 0 = <eds2 url="http://www.someurl.co.uk/_modules/system/Newsletter.aspx?Username=TBO&Password=N5TBO2&TagID=PlaceLogo&TownID=147">PlaceLogo</eds2>

Group 1 = <eds2 url="http://www.someurl.co.uk/_modules/system/Newsletter.aspx?Username=TBO&Password=N5TBO2&TagID=PlaceLogo&TownID=147">PlaceLogo</eds2>

Group 2 = http://www.someurl.co.uk/_modules/system/Newsletter.aspx?Username=TBO&Password=N5TBO2&TagID=PlaceLogo&TownID=147

Group 3 = PlaceLogo
```

Please clarify your question.

**UPDATE:**
I guess, your problem is the following:
You write the result of the match directly to your response stream **without** escaping it. This means, it will be interpreted as HTML and not as text, as you want.
You should change your code to this:

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"(?<ExternalSource2>\<eds2[\s.]+url\=\""?(?<Url>[\w\./:\?=&\+%\d_-]+)\""?[\s.]*\>(?<Text>[\s.]*[\w\s\d]*)\</eds2\>)");

string Input = @"width: 662px; height: 60px; vertical-align: middle""><eds2 url=""http://www.someurl.co.uk/_modules/system/Newsletter.aspx?Username=TBO&Password=N5TBO2&TagID=PlaceLogo&TownID=147"">PlaceLogo</eds2></td></tr></tbody></table><table style=""width: 662px; border-collapse: collapse""><tbod";

foreach (Match m in re.Matches(Input))
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("Match : {0}<br/>",
                                                     Server.HtmlEncode(m)));
    short i = 0;
    foreach (Group g in m.Groups)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response
                           .Write(string.Format("Group {0} = {1}<br/>", i++, 
                                                Server.HtmlEncode(g.Value)));
    }
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<br/><br/>");
}
```

Comment: Daniel, did you change anything at all in my code?  What you have is what I am expecting, but its not what I am getting.  This is driving me up the walls.  Is is possible that the Regex library in my .Net is somehow outdated?

Comment: I only changed the way the result is returned. Which might be the solution. I will update my answer in a sec.

Comment: Wow, I am an idiot.  You are correct, I am not HtmlEncoding it which is the cause of my 'problem'  Cant believe I wasted hours on this.  Thank you for pointing it out.